# Capistrano3 deployment error(ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, capistrano3

Getting the following error on bundle install during deployment with capistrano3

I have atomic gem in my Gemfile.lock with the specific version it asks me to install.
atomic (1.1.16) and having manually installed in my ec2 machine too. But during deployment it repeatedly says the following.

```
$cap development deploy

INFO [44c32ab1] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --binstubs /home/ec2-user/apps/dev/shared/bin --path /home/ec2-user/apps/dev/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on 54.201.16.12
DEBUG [44c32ab1] Command: cd /home/ec2-user/apps/dev/releases/20140423071010 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --binstubs /home/ec2-user/apps/dev/shared/bin --path /home/ec2-user/apps/ybench_dev/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet

DEBUG [44c32ab1]    Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
DEBUG [44c32ab1]    
DEBUG [44c32ab1]        /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
DEBUG [44c32ab1]    Cannot allocate memory - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb  2>&1
DEBUG [44c32ab1]    
DEBUG [44c32ab1]    Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/apps/dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/atomic-1.1.16 for inspection.
DEBUG [44c32ab1]    Results logged to /home/ec2-user/apps/dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/atomic-1.1.16/gem_make.out
DEBUG [44c32ab1]    An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
DEBUG [44c32ab1]    Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'` succeeds before bundling.
cap aborted!
```

Comment: i think you haven memory on your ec2 instance.try create swap on ec2 instance.

Comment: $df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  4.4G  3.5G  57% /
devtmpfs        285M   40K  285M   1% /dev
tmpfs           298M     0  298M   0% /dev/shm

Comment: Your problem is RAM, not disk space

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

https://github.com/classmethod-aws/ec2-swap

> ec2-swap: create and swapon swap image on EC2 instance store ec2-swap
>   is an RPM package project to create and swapon an swap image on EC2
>   instance store on Linux boot sequence.